# Draw Text with Specific Text Appearance

Tags: android, paint

How to draw text with a specific `TextAppearance`?

Here is my code.

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(false);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    // TODO: set the style of the text to a specific TextAppearance. E.g. @android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large.Inverse
    canvas.drawText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.myString), textOffsetX, textOffsetY, paint);
```

I have looked at `TypeFace` object, but I am not sure how to create a TypeFace from a TextAppearance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A coworker gave me a solution that uses a `TextView` as the a bridge for the `TextAppearance`

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large);
paint.setColor(textView.getCurrentTextColor());
paint.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize());
paint.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface());
```

Comment: Or you can just call `textView.getPaint()`.

Comment: Good start, but you have to use `AppCompatTextView` and `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance` for Typeface to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Base on [louis.luo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26723843/2729310) response, I found a solution which works on all API versions. You have to use `AppCompatTextView` and `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance` :

```
TextView textView = new AppCompatTextView(getContext());
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, styleRes);

//Just get paint from textview like janosch suggests
paint = textView.getPaint();

//Or get some info from textview
paint.setColor(textView.getCurrentTextColor());
paint.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize());
paint.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface());
```